# Converting a JSON Dictionary (currently a String) to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, type-conversion

I am using Python's request library to retrieve data from a web API. When viewing my data using `requests.text`, it returns a string of a large JSON object, e.g.,

```
'{"Pennsylvania": {"Sales": [{"date":"2021-12-01", "id": "Metric67", ... '
```

Naturally, the type of this object is currently a string. What is the best way to cover this string/JSON to a Pandas Dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.text` returns json as text.

You can use `r.json` to get json as dictionary from requests:

```py
import requests
r=requests.get(YOUR_URL)
res=r.json()
```